# How to make PHPSESSID secure and set sameSite to Strict

Tags: cookie, magento-enterprise-2, magento2.3.5

We are unable to set PHPSESSID secure and set sameSite value to Strict, does anyone have any idea how we can set this in Magento 2 EE.

[image]
Thanks

Comment: Mandar Parbate Were you able to find a solution for setting the SAMESITE attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need to set cookie setting properly.

Set-Cookie Domain at admin .

- https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/cookie-reference.html
- https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/compliance-cookie-restriction-mode.html

And also set Make `Use HTTP Only`  to yes.

See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821883/set-httponly-and-secure-on-phpsessid-cookie-in-php

Comment: I have set proper cookie setting

Comment: I have added screenshot. Please check